# Получение результата php скрипта без перезагрузки

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

Тема заезженная, но возникли трудности с ajax. Не могу вывести результат исполнения php-скрипта после отправки формы.
Алгоритм такой:

1. Вводим данные в форму
2. Передаем ее php скрипту
3. Выводим результат скрипта под формой ввода
   Сам код.

index.html

```
<form id="forma1" method="post" action="script.php">
    <label>Логин <input type="text" name="user_id" ></label>
    <br>
    <label>Пароль <input type="password" name="user_secret" ></label>
    <br>
    <input type="button" id="subBtn" value="Отправить">
    
    <br>
  
    <div id="result_form"></div>
</form>
```

JS

```
<script>
$('#subBtn').click(function(){
    $.post{
        'script.php',
        $('form1').serialize(),
        function(msg) { 
            $('#form1').hide('slow');
            alert(msg);
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

script.php

```
<?php
$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
$user_secret = $_POST['user_secret'];
$homepage = file_get_contents('https://example.com:9900/api/0/auth/access_token?user_id='.$user_id.'&user_secret='.$user_secret.'');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

Comment: `$('#subBtn').click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); //... }` и у формы Вашей `id="forma1"` а не `form1` а сериализуете Вы вообще не понятно что `$('form1').serialize()` такого элемента нет, как и здесь `$('#form1').hide('slow')`

Comment: `.serialize()` -- преобразует значения набора элементов в строку данных, Вам же потом нужно преобразовать это в массив, чтобы с ним рабоать посредством `$_POST['user_id']` и тд.

Comment: И ошибка в синтаксисе `$.post(url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ])`, а не `$.post{url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ]}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А зачем ВСЮ форму-то пытаться отправить? Насколько я вижу в `php` вы обрабатываете только два поля `user_id` и `user_secret`. Их и отправляйте

```
        $.ajax({
            url: 'script.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'user_id='+$('#forma1 input[type=text][name=user_id]').val()+'&user_secret='+$('#forma1 input[type=password][name=user_secret]').val(),
            error: function(req, text, error) {
                alert('Ajax Error:'+error);  
            },
            success: function ( msg) {
                if ( msg ) {
                   alert(msg);
                } else { alert('Unknown server response!'); }
            },
        });
```